# Потеря качества изображения при повторном просмотре

Tags: java, android

Есть активити с фоновым изображением. При первом просмотре этого активити – изображение отображается в хорошем качестве. Но если я сверну приложение и запущу его снова или открою другое активити(с другим изображением) и вернусь снова на данное активити, то изображение теряет качество и появляются (хоть и не сильно заметные) артефакты и шум. В чем причина?

**Код активити:**

```
public class StarsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tabLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new StarsActivity.CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getApplicationContext()));
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(0);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
    });
    //background
    ImageView background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background);

    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.stars_bg)
            .asBitmap()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(background);


    //back button
    ImageView back_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.arrow_back)
            .asBitmap()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .into(back_button);

    //home button
    ImageView home_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnBackToHome);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.home_button)
            .asBitmap()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .into(home_button);

    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
            button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });


    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if(position==0){
                button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if(position==1){
                button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();

}


public void onBackClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
}

public void onHomeClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private class CustomAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    private String fragments [] = {"•","•"};

    public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, Context applicationContext) {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new Fragment1();
            case 1:
                return new Fragment2();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragments[position];
    }
}
```

}

P.S. Для загрузки изображений использую библиотеку Glide.

P.S.S. На эмуляторе такого не наблюдаю. Только на реальных девайсах.

Comment: Вас проще будет понять, если вы предоставите скрины "до" и "после". А также укажете платформу/устройства на которых данное поведение отслеживается

Comment: изображение кэшируется?

Comment: или после каждого сворачивния занов скачивет?

Comment: @elik не знаю. Но загружаю я его вот так `Glide.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.stars_bg)
                .asBitmap()
                .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(background);`

Comment: яб посоветовал поработать откладчиком и проверить на сущность файл в который закачиветяс фотка .скорее всего у вас в жизненном цикле вкаждой фразе onResume идет показ и загрузка изображения

Comment: @elik А может ли быть проблема в кодировании?

Comment: Так проблема вкодировании и бывает

Comment: выложи сюда свой код посмотрим что там

Comment: @elik добавил код

Comment: не оно? https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1227
хотя, вроде, отмечено как закрытое.